# VPN on windows server interrupts connections on other interfaces

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, vpn

I've been given vpn access to a clients network. We set the vpn up using the built in vpn client in Windows server 2008.

When I connect to the VPN, it interrupts the connections to the physical interface of the server. How can I configure the vpn so that this doesnt happen.

I've already deselected the checkbox in the IPv4 properties that says " Use default gateway on remote network".

What else can I do?

Comment: Physical interface of what server?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to contact your client and ask if they will allow a split tunneling connection. Many corporates force all traffic through the VPN connection for security reasons. Enabling split tunneling, allows local traffic to bypass the VPN interface, but is considered a less secure setup by some.

Answer (score 0):

What are the IP addresses concerned?  I would suspect that the local LAN subnet is falling within the mask of the network at the far side of the VPN.

You may be able to overcome this by setting a very specific mask on the TCP/IP properties on the client VPN connection i.e. if ipconfig is showing 255.0.0.0 on connection then change it from automatic (DHCP) to 255.255.255.0, you will of course also need to specify a static IP

Comment: This is not the case.